# Downloads on play store are less than the Current Installs in play store statistics

Tags: android, download

On the play store I see 100 Downloads for my app and when I look at the statistics on Developer console, I see 165 as Current Installs.

What is the Download number supposed to signify?

Comment: nothing to do with programming

Comment: On the Play Store there are shown only milestones, which are 0 - 5, 10 - 50, 50 - 100, 100 - 500, etc.

Comment: @user6612167 Does you problem solved??

Comment: @ShaishavJogani yes it did, thank you

Comment: @user6612167 Then I would appreciate if you accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On play store they display number of downloads in range.

- 1 - 5
- 5 - 10
- 10 - 50
- 50 - 100
- 100 - 500
- 500 - 1000
- 1000 - 5000 and so on...

On the developer console you can see the exact number of downloads.